# Android, Java) Retrieve Bundle data as @StringDef?

Tags: java, android, enums

How can I check if the bundle passed from the previous Activity is one of @StringDef?

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@StringDef({Region.RegionA, Region.RegionB, Region.RegionC})
public @interface Region {
    String RegionA = "a";
    String RegionB = "b";
    String RegionC = "c";
}


private @Region String mRegion;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...
    mRegion = getArguments().getString("region"); // Check if this is @Region?
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this.

`//noinspection ResourceType
mRegion = getArguments().getString("region");`

Comment: What is this any why is it an accepted answer since its not working?